# One to many relation cascade persist fail

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-many

**The childrens dont find her parent.**
When I persist the children can't save the parent_id because I think parent is not persisted before.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=SaleQuoteRepository::class)
 */
class SaleQuote
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;
   /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=SaleQuoteLine::class, mappedBy="saleQuote", orphanRemoval=true,     cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $saleQuoteLines;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->saleQuoteLines = new ArrayCollection();
    }
 /**
     * @return Collection|SaleQuoteLine[]
     */
    public function getSaleQuoteLines(): Collection
    {
        return $this->saleQuoteLines;
    }

    public function addSaleQuoteLine(SaleQuoteLine $saleQuoteLine): self
    {
        if (!$this->saleQuoteLines->contains($saleQuoteLine)) {
            $this->saleQuoteLines[] = $saleQuoteLine;
            $saleQuoteLine->setSaleQuote($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeSaleQuoteLine(SaleQuoteLine $saleQuoteLine): self
    {
        if ($this->saleQuoteLines->removeElement($saleQuoteLine)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($saleQuoteLine->getSaleQuote() === $this) {
                $saleQuoteLine->setSaleQuote(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

**The child related**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=SaleQuoteLineRepository::class)
 */
class SaleQuoteLine
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=SaleQuote::class, inversedBy="saleQuoteLines", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="saleQuote_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $saleQuote;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    
    public function getSaleQuote(): ?SaleQuote
    {
        return $this->saleQuote;
    }

    public function setSaleQuote(?SaleQuote $saleQuote): self
    {
        $this->saleQuote = $saleQuote;

        return $this;
    }
```

Error say I can't persist because I can't find my parent Id:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: SaleQuoteLine.saleQuote_id

Comment: I may be wrong but I believe in this scenario you just need to be calling `persist` solely on the parent and, that call should cascade to the children. However, you may need to fully persist the parent and call `flush` before adding children.

Comment: Someone may be able to help more if you add your controller CRUD action(s) and your form(s).

Comment: @Arleigh Hix I have tested... change nothing children have no parent_id.